# What exactly happens during object creation? (Java)

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance, constructor

I've been studying from *Head First Java* and I'm currently on the constructors chapter. They've explained that an object is created by calling a constructor after the `new` keyword.

My question: What is it exactly that runs when you create a new object? 
 
 Let's take the following as sample code:

```
public class Const {

    // instance variables
    int number;
    String name;


    // Constructors
    public Const() {
        //implicit super
        System.out.println("no-arg constructor");
    }
    public Const(int i, String s) {
        //implicit super()
        number = i;
        name = s;
        System.out.println("two-arg constructor");
    }


    // test method
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm a test");
    }


    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Const c1 = new Const();
        Const c2 = new Const(5, "Jerry");
    }
}
```

Now here is what I believe is happening under the hood when creating `c1`:

1. `public Const()` is called
2. `super()` is called
3. the `Object` part of Const is built.
4. `public Const()` is back on top of the stack.
5. Now here comes my trouble. When and how exactly are the instance variables and methods for the object created (what implicit code is added)?

Comment: You seem to have asked 4 questions instead of one

Comment: The exact details vary by implementations. But actually, what happens is that the object is first allocated in memory, including everything, all the fields and required references. Then the initializers and constructors are called.

Comment: I suspect https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5 will answer most of your questions.

Comment: Apologies, question modified. @JonSkeet thanks for documentation. Clears it up somewhat :)

Comment: @JonSkeet has spoken!!!!!

Comment: *"What EXACTLY happens now?"* 1) The `println` call is executed, 2) the constructor returns, and 3) the reference to the new object is assigned to `c1`. --- What else did you expect to happen? Nothing magical goes on from that point (after the implicit `super()` call returns).

Comment: @JonSkeet correction... COMPLETELY cleared up my doubts. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly happens during object creation? (Java)

- Constructor being called, which will call the super method of the parent Class(By Default Object class, so the new Class will have access of all members of  Object class)
- Memory Allocation
- Fields are initialized (by assigned value or if not given then by default value)
- rest code block of the constructor will be executed

So the only difference here is:

```
Const c1 = new Const();
```

Here number will be initialized by   int default value which is **0** and name will be initialized by **null**, which is the default value of String

```
Const c2 = new Const(5, "Jerry");
```

Instead here it will be 5 and Jerry respecively

With the **new Const()**, the constructor will be called and the class will be loaded to the main memory.

```
public Const() {
        //implicit super 
        super()
    }
```

The super keyword in java is a reference variable that is used to refer parent class objects, which is by default Object class. The keyword “super” came into the picture with the concept of Inheritance.

So now it has access of all members of Object class i.e. toString, equals :

as you can access

```
c1.toString() or c1.equals(obj)
```

> When and how exactly are the instance variables and methods for the
>   object created (what implicit code is added)?

I think now you understood how instance variables are created, and the default values are assigned to them based on the type.

If still not clear, try to understand the internal arch, that might help:

[JVM Arch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXIxQ.png)